# Is there a simple way to show .gitignore rules that are not matched by any file in the directory tree?

Tags: git, gitignore

I need to clean up my .gitignore file. I run some commands and then go through the .gitignore file and delete any line that isn't needed anymore.

The command finds all files in a tree, runs git's check-ignore, greps out only matches that are in my .gitignore file, cleans up the line, and then uniquely sorts the results. Any rule that doesn't appear in this output is a candidate for removal.

```
find . -type f -not -path .git -exec git check-ignore -v '{}' \; | grep '^.gitignore:' | sed 's/.*:\(.*\)\t.*$/\1/' | sort -u >> .gitignore
```

This command can take quite some time, especially in repositories with a lot of files and mounted on an NFS.

Is there a simpler method that will show me rules that are not matched by any file in the tree?

Comment: you could clone the repository somewhere else and run your liner only on the files that are missing on the clean clone. However, are you sure you that all the rules that are not triggered at a given moment have to be removed ?

Comment: I know not all of the 'unused' lines are actually unused. That's why I said 'candidate for removal' instead of just auto-deleting them.  I have a number of repositories and a large number of developers who are not quite used to the concept of revision control. So, .gitignore needs to be cleaned out on a regular basis.

Comment: Also, as for cloning to a clean spot, I tried that. While it helped, it didn't outweigh the annoyance factor of doing this to multiple repositories and wasn't any more reliable.

Comment: I'd need the same for `.gitattributes`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [git status --ignored=matching](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---ignoredltmodegt) to get a list of the ignored file that matches a pattern in `.gitignore`.

```
git status -s --ignored=matching | grep "^\!\!" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git check-ignore -v | grep '^.gitignore:' | sed 's/.*:\(.*\)\t.*$/\1/' | sort -u >> .gitignore
```

Comment: The version of git in RHEL 7 is woefully outdated. I don't have the '=matching' option, so I don't know what's different. This does not give me the same output as my posted command. Off to do some experimenting.

Comment: the main point  here is - read the docs, look for the command how to show the ignored files with `git` instead of using `find` and apply your logic on this list

Comment: 'git status -s --ignored --untracked-files' with your changes gives me what I want, and in 12 seconds instead of 4.5 minutes. Nice. Thanks.